# PubSub framework + Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data, publish-subscribe

Is it possible to persist PubSub framework objects in a Core Data persistent store? Or is there a better way to do this...? I'm working on an RSS reader and looking for ways to cache RSS/Atom feeds retrieved by PubSub..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to persist PubSub objects in the persistent store, however, I am not sure if it is needed as I believe those objects are persisted in an operating system database.

Regardless, to do this, all you have to is add a transformable property, i.e. feedObject. The docs have a good explanation of how to do this:[DOCS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)

The only real trick is that you have to import the PubSub framework on the Entity header file.

Like I said though, the feeds and associated entries are all persisted (I believe) in the operating system as long as you subscribe to the feed. The only time it retrieves entries is (a) when you first subscribe to a feed and (b) when it decides that is time to refresh the feed.

If you don't subscribe to the feed and you are only taking the feeds manually then you might want to consider adding them to your persistent store.

Answer (score 0):

there is an example in the mac developer site regarding reading news feeds. The sample code can be downloaded by clicking [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NewsReader/Introduction/Intro.html). Hope it will be useful for you.

[here](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/02/pubsub-framework-using-rss-feeds-in.html) is another example by [Colin Wheeler](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com)